# How do I use a TabLayoutMediator for viewPager2 in android?

Tags: java, android

Please I am trying to create a tab view inside a fragment,
I created the tabs and view page2 in home layout and created a tabView Adapter, then I had to make the connections in my Home fragment class.

[image: This is the code for the tab view connection]

the challenge now is the tabs stopped showing immediately I added the tab layout mediator below the

```
viewPager2.setAdapter(tabVPAdapter);

 new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager2,
            (tab, position) -> tab.setText("OBJECT " + (position + 1))
    ).attach();
```

Please the image above is what I would love to achieve
[image: I expected this to show with the view pager working appropriately]

But when  I ran the application this is what I got
[image]

I could not find the tabs any more and I checked the LogCat but did not see any error message.

Please what do I do?

Comment: From the image it looks like the view pager is added (empty space below the label "transaction logs".
Did you add a breakpoint to the mediator and check, whether any data is attached from the adapter?

Comment: I just removed the tabLayoutMediator and the tabs are showing but the view pager is not working so I can not see any tab view page when I click on any of the tab.

Comment: I  forgot to add the return value to the getItemCount() method of my adapter class

Comment: So problem solved then? If so, please make a post and answer your questions in order for others to find a solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add the return value to the getItemCount() method of my adapter class